# onClick Button Only Works Once

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I have a button that checks input text to see if it is the right password. The problem is that the button only works once and when you click multiple times it doesn't run the function over and over again.

My Code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Password</title>
  <script>
  function passcheck() {
    var attempts = 5;
    var q = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    if (q == "12345") {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You're In!";
    } else {
      attempts--;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Wrong password, You Have " + attempts + " Tries Left!";
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <font face="Verdana" size="5"><b>Enter Your Password:</b></font>
  <br/><br/>
  <input id="txt" type="text" onclick="this.select()" style="text-align:center;" width="25">
  <button type="button" onclick="passcheck()">Submit!</button>
  <p id="result"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being called multiple times, but you aren't seeing a change because `attempts` is defined inside of the function. That means that every time you run that functions, `attempts` is being reset to `5`. To fix that, move the `attempts` declaration *outside* of the function.

```js
var attempts = 5; // Moved to here so we don't reset the value

function passcheck() {
  var q = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  if (q == "12345") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You're In!";
  } else {
    attempts--;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Wrong password, You Have " + attempts + " Tries Left!";
  }
}
```

```html
<font face="Verdana" size="5"><b>Enter Your Password:</b></font>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="txt" type="text" onclick="this.select()" style="text-align:center;" width="25">
<button type="button" onclick="passcheck()">Submit!</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the value of "attempts" and decrementing it every time you call the function. Hence it seems like the function is being called only once.

Move the deceleration of the variable outside the function. Something like

```
var attempts = 5;
function passcheck() {
  //code here ...
}
```

Another slightly better way would be to make use of [localStorage or sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) or even using cookies.

Thanks,
Paras